# How to extract all the URLs from the text in android

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to get all the URLs from the given text using `Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(qrText);`

**What I want to do:**

I am scanning a QR code,

- open the link in webView if the link contains link which contians the word "veridoc"
- showing in textView if the text scanned is not link or another link that does not contain the word "veridoc"

**What I have tried:**

```
private void initialize() {
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_LINK) != null) {
        qrText = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_LINK);
        webMatcher = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(qrText);
    }

    if (qrText.contains("veridoc") && webMatcher.matches()) {
            //if qr text is veridoc link
            Log.e("veridoc link", qrText);
            setupWebView(qrText, false);
        } else if (webMatcher.matches()) {
            //if qr text is link other than veridoc
            Log.e("link", qrText);
            openInBrowser(qrText);
            finish();
        } else if  (qrText.contains("veridoc") && webMatcher.find()) {
            //if qrText contains veridoc link + other text.
            String url = webMatcher.group();

            if (url.contains("veridoc")) {
                Log.e("veridoc link found", url);
                setupWebView(url, true);
            } else
                showQRText(qrText);
        } else {
            //the qrText neither is a link nor contains any link that contains word veridoc
            showQRText(qrText);
        }
    } 
}
```

In the above code,

- `setupWebView(String strUrl, boolean isTextAndUrlBoth)`  setup webview and load url etc.
- `openInBrowser(String url)` opens the provided URL in the browser.
- `showQRText(String text)` shows the provided text in textView with formatting.

**The Issue**

When the text contains some text and more than 1 link, `String url = webMatcher.group();` always fetches the first link in the text.

**What I want**

I want all the links from the text, and find out that which links contain the word "veridoc". After that I would like to call the method `setupWebView(url, true);` .

**I am using following link and text for Example**

name: Something 
Profession: Something
link1: https://medium.com/@rkdaftary/understanding-git-for-beginners-20d4b55cc72c
link 2:  https://my.veridocglobal.com/login
Can anyone help me to find all the links present in the text?

Comment: add sample text with link which you are using

Comment: The problem in your code is, you are only calling `webMatcher.find()` in an `if` loop due to which it only returns the first matching URL, which may or may not have `veridoc` within it. Hence you will need to use `webMatcher.find()` in a while loop to extract all matches and check if the matched URL contains `veridoc` Can you show what your `Patterns.WEB_URL` declaration looks like and also add some sample text where you are having problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop on find to find the different websites and setup arraylists with that

```
Matcher webMatcher = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(input);
ArrayList<String> veridocLinks = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> otherLinks = new ArrayList<>();

while (webMatcher.find()){
    String res = webMatcher.group();
    if(res!= null) {
        if(res.contains("veridoc")) veridocLinks.add(res);
        else otherLinks.add(res);
    }
}
```

Given a sample input like :

```
String input = "http://www.veridoc.com/1 some text http://www.veridoc.com/2 some other text http://www.othersite.com/3";
```

Your ArrayLists will contains :

```
veridocLinks : "http://www.veridoc.com/1", "http://www.veridoc.com/2"
otherLinks : "http://www.othersite.com/3"
```